# vb.net showdialog openfile to string

Tags: vb.net, string, showdialog

i'm trying to importe a csv file after creating on the same application, the only probleme is that even if a string matchs a line from the file, comparing them on vb.net dosn't give a true boolean i know i didn't make any mistakes because of the line with the commentary 'THIS LINE  , i use a pretty small list to do my test and in that loop, there is always one element that matches exactly the string, but comparing them on vb.net dosn't return a true. the result of this is that just after saving the file to my computer while still having it on my listview1 on the application, i load it to the application again and it duplicates everything

```
Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
open.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv*)|*.csv"
If open.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim File As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(open.FileName)
    Dim lines() As String = File.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    For i = 1 To (lines.Count - 1)
        Dim line As String = lines(i)
        Dim Columns() As String = line.Split(";")
        Dim addLin As New ListViewItem(Columns)
        Dim Alr As Boolean = False
        Dim st as string=listView1.Items.Item(k).SubItems.Item(0).Text
        For k = 0 To (ListView1.Items.Count - 1)
            Dim st as string=listView1.Items.Item(k).SubItems.Item(0).Text
            MsgBox(Columns(0)& Environment.NewLine & st) 'THIS LINE
            If ListView1.Items.Item(k).SubItems.Item(0).Text = Columns(0) Then
                Alr = True
                MsgBox("true") 'never showsup even when the previous one show the match
            End If
        next
        If Alr = False Then
            MsgBox("false")                  'the msgbox is only to check
            ListView1.Items.Add(addLin)
        End If
    next
end if
```

Comment: Sometimes what seems to be equal to the human eye is not really equal.
Try use Trim on both strings, for starters. also, unless you need a case-sensitive comparison, use ToLower or ToUpper on both strings (this is something that you will probably not miss in a visual compare, but it's still good practice).

Comment: no but the file i opened was just saved from the same listview wih the same data, then i loaded it again, nothing changed, but the string comparing dosn't return true

Comment: Still, you saved it to a file and loaded it again. perhaps the csv format adds spaces. it doesn't take a long time to check...

Comment: you need to turn on Option Strict.  the variable k is used before it is declated and 'st' is multiply defined.  what are do you want to happen with this line: `Dim addLin As New ListViewItem(lines)` ?

Comment: zohar, as strange as it sounds, it actually worked, thank you Oo i added the trim to column(0) and now the app can return true when comparing them, and plutonix the code works, nothing is in its wrong place, and the dim addlin is used for ListView1.Items.Add(addLin), so i can add multicolumn items in the listview, and what do you mean by option strict